Why webservice can't return datatable in ASP.NET C#
I use this code to call an ASP.NET C# web service to access a SQL Server table:
HttpResponseMessage message2 = client.GetAsync("GetAll?Columns=*&Tbl=Coding_Sell").Result;

string userJson2 = message2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
MessageBox.Show(userJson2);

DataTable DT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(userJson2);

This is my web method:
[WebMethod]
public string GetAll(string Columns, string Tbl)
{
    return ObjdBAccess.Get(Columns, Tbl);
}

And its related class is as follows:
public string Get(string Columns, string TableName)
{
    String query = "SELECT " + Columns + " From " + TableName;
    createConn();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(DS);

    DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0];

    closeConn();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DS);
}

But the program fails in this line:
DataTable DT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(userJson2);

with the following error:

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

And this is my userJson2 variable:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"Table":[{"Main_Code":51,"Property_Name":"Sell","Sub_Code":"1"},{"Main_Code":52,"Property_Name":"Sell2","Sub_Code":"2"}]}</string>

Please tell me what is wrong with my code.

By default, ASP.NET web method returns the response in XML. You should modify the response so that it returns as JSON:
[WebMethod]
public static void GetAll(string Columns, string Tbl)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ObjdBAccess.Get(Columns, Tbl));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}

Or you may work with the ScriptMethod attribute.
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetAll(string Columns, string Tbl)
{
    return ObjdBAccess.Get(Columns, Tbl);
}

For deserializing the JSON response as it is an object instead of array:
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(userJson2);
DataTable DT = jObj["Table"].ToObject<DataTable>();


Thanks for your answer. But it does not work because:

HttpContext.Current.Response does not have any responsetype extension method.
Wirting to ObjdBAccess can't be done in the staticvoid.


Use ContentType instead of ResponseType. For 2nd approach, make sure you are using use string return type.

ContentType is OK.
For the 2nd, I rechanged the webmethod to "public string GetAll(string Columns, string Tbl)" instead of static void and add "return HttpContext.Current.Response.ToString();" to this method.
New error like this:
Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
This is new userJson2:
{"Table":[{"Main_Code":51,"Property_Name":"Sell","Sub_Code":"1"},{"Main_Code":52,"Property_Name":"Sell2","Sub_Code":"2"}]}

Hi sorry, updated the answer again.

All things are correct except than the last line: DataTable DT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jObj["Table"]); Because Can not convert from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken to String
But with this line everything is ok
DataTable DT = jObj["Table"].ToObject();
Thanks a lot for your nice help.
